# can't execute mysql request via R

Tags: sql, r

I am having difficulty. I need to get the desired result through mysql query in R .
my attempt.

```
load libraries which i use.

library(RMySQL)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(Rcpp)
library(zoo)
library(gsubfn)
library(proto)
library(RSQLite)
library(DBI)
library(RMariaDB)
library(dbx)
```

then i try perform connect

```
getDf <- function (connect, sql)
{
  str(paste("EXECUTE:    ", sql))
  query <- dbSendQuery(connect, sql)
  df <- dbFetch(query, n = -1)
  dbClearResult(query)
  str(paste("ROW FETCHED:", nrow(df)))
  df
}
then
db_user <- 'k'
db_password <- 'F'
db_name <- 'yyy'
db_table <- 'mytable'
db_host <- 'xxx' # for local access
db_port <- 3306


readDB <- dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), user = db_user, pass = db_password, dbname = db_name, host = db_host, port = db_port)
```

and here i try get prepared data via query mysql

```
df333 <- getDf(readDB, paste("UPDATE incoming_aggregation_google ia
JOIN data_aggregation_google_median dm ON 
    (ia.agency_id = dm.agency_id)
    AND (ia.search_category_id = dm.search_category_id)
    AND (ia.offer_category_id = dm.offer_category_id)
    AND (ia.flight_codes = dm.flight_codes)
    AND (ia.search_type_category_id = dm.search_type_category_id)
SET ia.prediction_diff_percent_base_price = dm.median_diff_percent_base_price + (0.4 * RAND() - 0.2);
UPDATE incoming_aggregation_google_general ia
JOIN data_aggregation_google_general_median dm ON 
    (ia.agency_id = dm.agency_id)
    AND (ia.offer_category_id = dm.offer_category_id)
    AND (ia.search_type_category_id = dm.search_type_category_id)
    AND (ia. service_discount_category_id = dm. service_discount_category_id)
SET ia.prediction_diff_percent_base_price = dm.median_diff_percent_base_price + (0.4 * RAND() - 0.2);
UPDATE incoming_aggregation_google_general da
JOIN data_aggregation_google_general_median i  ON 
(
    i.agency_id=da.agency_id 
    AND i.offer_category_id=da.offer_category_id 
    AND i.service_discount_category_id=da.service_discount_category_id 
    AND i.search_type_category_id=da.search_type_category_id
  )
set da.prediction_diff_percent_base_price = i.median_diff_percent_base_price;", db_table))
```

but the error

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE incoming_aggregation_google_general ia
JOIN data_aggregation_google_gener' at line 9 [1064]
```

Please help me understand what I did wrong and how to fix it? If what I want to do is not can be done, is there a way to translate the `essence of this query` into logic R.
Thanks for your any valuable help

Comment: The error indicates the is be wholly within your SQL code, not in R. If you want help doing it in R, show us sample input data, desired output, and explain what you want to do in words. If you want to do it in SQL, strip the R out of your question, and ask for help on the SQL code. Probably the same things would help: a little sample input, desired output, and explanation in words.

Comment: It may also help to debug the SQL query in a SQL editor, MySQL Workbench is popular for working with MySQL.